# Logging arrays by convention in js

Tags: javascript, combinations, conventions

This is the code to find all combinations:

```
function make(arr, el) {
    var i, i_m, item;
    var len = 4;
    var res = [];
  
    for(i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
      res.push(
        ([]).concat(
          arr.slice(0, i),
          [el],
          arr.slice(i, i_m)
        )
      );
    }
  
    return res;
  }
  
  function combinations(arr) {
    var prev, curr, el, i;
    var len = 4;
  
    curr = [[arr[0]]];
  
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++) {
      el = arr[i];
      prev = curr;
      curr = [];
  
      prev.forEach(function(item) {
        curr = curr.concat(
          make(item, el)
        );
      });
    }
    return curr;
  }
  
  m = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99]
  combinations(m)
```

But I want console.log(combinations(m)) outputs only arrays that satisfies the condition. It should find all the combinations, where `first element/second element == 2*first element+third element/(2*second element+fourth element) == 3*first element+2*third element/(3*second element+2*fourth element)`

I tried to use «if», but always getting an error. How can I do this?

Comment: show us you code for the conditions

Comment: Please show us the erroring if statement.

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu
`function combinations(arr) {
    var prev, curr, el, i;
    var len = 4;
  
    curr = [[arr[0]]];
  
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++) {
      el = arr[i];
      prev = curr;
      curr = [];
  
      prev.forEach(function(item) {
        curr = curr.concat(
          make(item, el)
        );
      });
    }

    if (curr[0]/curr[1] == 2*curr[0]+curr[2]/(2*curr[1]+curr[3]) == 3*curr[0]+2*curr[2]/(3*curr[1]+2*curr[3])) {
        return curr;
    }
  }`